# Load Balancing Between Two elasticsearch servers

Tags: elasticsearch, load-balancing

I have two ElasticSearch Servers:

```
http://12.13.54.333:9200
```

and

```
http://65.98.54.10:9200
```

In the first server I have 100k of data(`id`=1 to `id`=100k) and in the second server I have 100k of data(`id`=100k+1 to 200k).

I want to have a text search for the keyword `obama` in one request on both servers. Is this possible?

Comment: Are the two nodes part of the same cluster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is a little generic...I'll try not to give an "it depends" kind of answer, but in order to do so I have to make a couple of assumptions.

Are those two servers actually two nodes on the same elasticsearch cluster? I suppose so.

Did you index data on an elasticsearch index composed of more than one shard? I suppose so. The default in elasticsearch is five shards, which in your case would lead to having two shards on one node and three on the other.

Then you can just send your query to one of those nodes via REST API. The query will be executed on all the shards that the index (can be even more than one) you are querying is composed of. If you have replicas the replica shards might be used too at query time. The node that received your query will then reduce the search results got from all the shards returning back the most relevant ones.

To be more specific the search phase on every shard will most likely only collect the document ids and their score. Once the node that you hit has reduced the results, it can fetch all the needed fields (usually the [_source field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/source-field/)) only for the documents that it's supposed to return.

What's nice about elasticsearch is that even if you indexed data on different indexes you can query multiple indices and everything is going to work the same as I described. At the end of the day every index is composed of shards, and querying ten indices with one shard each is the same as querying one index with ten shards.

What I described applies to the default [search_type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/search-type/) that elasticsearch uses, called `query_then_fetch`. There are other search types that you can eventually use when needed, like for example the count which doesn't do any reduce nor fetch but just returns the number of hits for a query executing it on all shards and returning the sum of all the hits for each shard.

Answer (score 1):

Revendra Kumar,

Elasticsearch should handler that for you. Elasticsearch was built from scratch to be distributed and do distributed search.

Basically, if those servers are in the same cluster, you will have a two shards (the first one holds the id from 1 to 100k and the second one hold the ids from 100001 to 200k). When you search by something, it doesn't matter which server it hits, it will do a search on both servers and returns the result for the client. The internal behavior of elasticsearch is too extensive to explain here.